# Unique random number each instance it is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I want a variable that generates a random number from .1 to 1. Within a function i want to refer to that variable several times each reference should generate a unique number… If that ramble makes sense. There have been things that glance on it but usually in C or some other language. I need this in javascript.

`var randoms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + .15;`

I have this code here, I reference it within the same function about 15 times.
Each of those times I want the number to be different. As it stands this generates one unique number that then gets used 15 times.

I know it must be simple as it is a simple a concept, yet I cannot wrap my mind around it.

some guidance would be amazing.

perhaps some context will help.
here i have a gang of bar variables that at a certain point on a timeline I need them to trigger a width animation but at different rates of time.

below the var **randoms** needs to change for each instance it is called for all of the bar elements.

```
var bar1 = $('#bar1'),
    bar2 = $('#bar2'),
    bar3 = $('#bar3'),
    bar4 = $('#bar4'),
    bar5 = $('#bar5'),
    bar6 = $('#bar6'),
    bar7 = $('#bar7'),
    bar8 = $('#bar8'),
    bar9 = $('#bar9'),
    bar10 = $('#bar10'),
    bar11 = $('#bar11'),
    bar12 = $('#bar12'),
    bar13 = $('#bar13'),
    bar14 = $('#bar14'),
    bar15 = $('#bar15')
    icon = $('.icon'), 
    randoms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + .15;


    init = new TimelineMax();

    init.add ("chart" , "+=2")
    init.to(icon_1, 0.5, {alpha: '1'})
        .to(icon_2, 0.5, {alpha: '1'})
        .to(icon_3, 0.5, {alpha: '1'})
        .to(icon_4, 0.5, {alpha: '1'})
        .to(bar1, randoms, {width: '100%'},'chart')
        .to(bar2, randoms, {width: '100%'},'chart')
        .to(bar3, randoms, {width: '75%'},'chart')
        .to(bar4, randoms, {width: '90%'},'chart')
        .to(bar5, randoms, {width: '85%'},'chart')
        .to(bar6, randoms, {width: '100%'},'chart')
        .to(bar7, randoms, {width: '75%'},'chart')
        .to(bar8, randoms, {width: '90%'},'chart')
        .to(bar9, randoms, {width: '90%'},'chart')
        .to(bar10, randoms, {width: '70%'},'chart')
        .to(bar11, randoms, {width: '50%'},'chart')
        .to(bar12, randoms, {width: '85%'},'chart')
        .to(bar13, randoms, {width: '80%'},'chart')
        .to(bar14, randoms, {width: '90%'},'chart')
        .to(bar15, randoms, {width: '90%'},'chart');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you code will never produce a value different from `0.15`. You are calling `Math.floor` on your random value which immediately converts it to 0. To generate a number between .1 to 1 use:

```
var randoms = Math.random() * 0.9 + 0.1;
```

Secondly, once the variable is set, it will never update and get a new value. You need to call the code above as many times as numbers you need. Once way to achieve this is by wrapping it in a function:

```
function randoms() {
    return Math.random() * 0.9 + 0.1;
}
console.log(randoms());
```

**Edit:**
Here's how to use the above function:

```
function randoms() {
    return Math.random() * 0.9 + 0.1;
}
init.to(icon_1, 0.5, {alpha: '1'})
        .to(icon_2, 0.5, {alpha: '1'})
        .to(icon_3, 0.5, {alpha: '1'})
        .to(icon_4, 0.5, {alpha: '1'})
        .to(bar1, randoms(), {width: '100%'},'chart')
        .to(bar2, randoms(), {width: '100%'},'chart')
        .to(bar3, randoms(), {width: '75%'},'chart')
        .to(bar4, randoms(), {width: '90%'},'chart')
        .to(bar5, randoms(), {width: '85%'},'chart')
        .to(bar6, randoms(), {width: '100%'},'chart')
        .to(bar7, randoms(), {width: '75%'},'chart')
        .to(bar8, randoms(), {width: '90%'},'chart')
        .to(bar9, randoms(), {width: '90%'},'chart')
        .to(bar10, randoms(), {width: '70%'},'chart')
        .to(bar11, randoms(), {width: '50%'},'chart')
        .to(bar12, randoms(), {width: '85%'},'chart')
        .to(bar13, randoms(), {width: '80%'},'chart')
        .to(bar14, randoms(), {width: '90%'},'chart')
        .to(bar15, randoms(), {width: '90%'},'chart');
```

Comment: Yeah i just noticed the first issue thanks for pointing that out. Secondly I am trying to work it into a function to get a unique number upon every call I think i am really handcuffing myself using greensock vs jquery i might have to explore another method of animation.

Comment: Holy hell I never thought to use a function as the time parameter, so obvious—Ill have to give this a shot to see if the tweening engine will allow for this, although i cannot see a reason why. I understood your point and have tried updating the randoms variable upon completion of animation in order to change the number generated on each instance, but that didn't work , now ill have to try this. Thanks, not that you care but ill keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function to create a random number from `0.1` to `1.0` :

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*11) / 10 ;
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e5rre036/)

if you want to create random number from 0 to n, try :

```
var random = Math.floor( Math.random()* n+1 );
```

Comment: So this works by putting the variable in a for loop?

Comment: This is incorrect. Your fiddle generates 0's occasionally.

Comment: yes, you can also put defined variable or you can use static values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide how many unique numbers you want. Then every time you get a number match it with your previous number for uniqueness. Finally you'll have a unique set of numbers. For range between .1 to 1, [***Math.random()***](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) returns random value from 0(inclusive) to 1(exclusive). Avoid `0` using an if statement.

```
var counter = 10;
var uniqueNumbers = new Array();
interval = setInterval(function(){
    var x = Number(Math.random().toFixed(1));
    if(uniqueNumbers.indexOf(x) == -1  & x != 0.0){
        uniqueNumbers.push(x);
        console.log(uniqueNumbers);
    }
    if(uniqueNumbers.length == counter){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1);
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/bug9ww9n/)

***Another Solution :***

You can also wrap your code inside a function and get a distinct value everytime you call that function. Try this code below,

***HTML :***

```
<button id="getRandom">Get Unique Number</button>
```

***javaScript :***

```
var counter = 0;
var numberLimit = 5;
var uniqueNumbers = new Array();

getRandom.onclick = function(){
    if(counter != numberLimit){
        CalculateRandom();
    }
};

function CalculateRandom(){
    var x = Number(Math.random().toFixed(1));
    if(uniqueNumbers.indexOf(x) == -1  & x != 0.0){
        uniqueNumbers.push(x);
        console.log(uniqueNumbers);
        counter++;
    } else if(counter != numberLimit){
        CalculateRandom();
    }
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/0yrvukze/)

[***Note :*** *You can also set the decimal places as you wish.* ]

Answer (score 0):

Nikola offered the solution I was looking for. My random typos in code aside— the concept of creating a function that refreshes the random time variable, then calling that particular function in place where the time parameter of the animation is, works brilliantly. In this case I used tweenMax but could easily translate to a setInterval or any number of parameters that require one variable to change every time its is called.